# How can I access dataset from Nasa website

Tags: dataset

So Now I was working on my project ("Failure prediction models in FoF") and the Tool I will be using is RapidMinder but I need to have a dataset to run the tool on, I found a nice description of dataset that could be helpful on Nasa website https://data.nasa.gov/external-dataset?datasetId=dc5d-zf5v , However I do not know how to access the data itself in form of CSV file.

Comment: How is that a nice description of a dataset? It looks like a description of a project that wants to "mine large, distributed, heterogeneous data systems". Why do you think that dataset would be available as a CSV, or even available at all?

Answer (score 1):

It [seems that there is no downloadable data](http://techport.nasa.gov/view/9418) (I clicked *Show the complete Project library*), but the project was completed in 2012, so you could ask the listed contact, Gary Jahns, explaining your motivation, to be sure: `gary.c.jahns@nasa.gov`